# Assign depth of elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, depth

I have an array of groups. Each group has a 'groups' array. It can either be empty, meaning that this group does not have subgroups, or it can have indexes of other groups, which are the subgroups of that group.

```
var groups = [{
  "leaves": [],
  "groups": [1],
  "label": "A",
  "id": "5fe7a8ee-abd2-45d9-a79b-ff48e216f537",
  "parentGroup": null,
  "padding": 30
}, {
  "leaves": [],
  "groups": [2, 5, 8, 9],
  "label": "B",
  "id": "567e8de7-3aff-4b02-a891-b90a78bbf99f",
  "parentGroup": "5fe7a8ee-abd2-45d9-a79b-ff48e216f537",
  "padding": 30
}, {
  "leaves": [],
  "groups": [3, 4],
  "label": "C",
  "id": "56d73322-2601-477c-8e6f-dc3623cc37ed",
  "parentGroup": "567e8de7-3aff-4b02-a891-b90a78bbf99f",
  "padding": 30
}, {
  "leaves": [0],
  "groups": [],
  "label": "D",
  "id": "cc4e72f8-1844-4334-9796-60a0e1566331",
  "parentGroup": "56d73322-2601-477c-8e6f-dc3623cc37ed",
  "padding": 30
}, {
  "leaves": [1],
  "groups": [],
  "label": "E",
  "id": "0ffbc1a8-8ce3-4e37-bf4f-6f3283a5d8d2",
  "parentGroup": "56d73322-2601-477c-8e6f-dc3623cc37ed",
  "padding": 30
}, {
  "leaves": [],
  "groups": [6, 7],
  "label": "F",
  "id": "75b62737-0270-4569-8772-7d88eeffc801",
  "parentGroup": "567e8de7-3aff-4b02-a891-b90a78bbf99f",
  "padding": 30
}, {
  "leaves": [2],
  "groups": [],
  "label": "G",
  "id": "c69d6171-e834-4788-a206-64b7721a1022",
  "parentGroup": "75b62737-0270-4569-8772-7d88eeffc801",
  "padding": 30
}, {
  "leaves": [3],
  "groups": [],
  "label": "H",
  "id": "8f6b7a33-6156-4495-9ece-7acd16284ba8",
  "parentGroup": "75b62737-0270-4569-8772-7d88eeffc801",
  "padding": 30
}, {
  "leaves": [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  "groups": [],
  "label": "I",
  "id": "c4541ca8-c0f2-4694-a7a6-17092ad881ca",
  "parentGroup": "567e8de7-3aff-4b02-a891-b90a78bbf99f",
  "padding": 30
}, {
  "leaves": [9],
  "groups": [],
  "label": "J",
  "id": "f6f93345-991e-4759-8aaf-b65f016c4d8f",
  "parentGroup": "567e8de7-3aff-4b02-a891-b90a78bbf99f",
  "padding": 30
}, {
  "leaves": [],
  "groups": [11, 12, 13, 14],
  "label": "K",
  "id": "5d7de0ab-7949-412c-acc3-8e6f2f63b6ca",
  "parentGroup": null,
  "padding": 30
}, {
  "leaves": [10, 11],
  "groups": [],
  "label": "L",
  "id": "a997ab55-d8f2-436b-95e2-1635d98fdb5d",
  "parentGroup": "5d7de0ab-7949-412c-acc3-8e6f2f63b6ca",
  "padding": 30
}, {
  "leaves": [12],
  "groups": [],
  "label": "M",
  "id": "3cbaed7e-e3ca-4686-beb6-2599e56981c6",
  "parentGroup": "5d7de0ab-7949-412c-acc3-8e6f2f63b6ca",
  "padding": 30
}, {
  "leaves": [13],
  "groups": [],
  "label": "N",
  "id": "033b3242-6ff9-4bf0-833f-2042b9cb6978",
  "parentGroup": "5d7de0ab-7949-412c-acc3-8e6f2f63b6ca",
  "padding": 30
}, {
  "leaves": [14],
  "groups": [],
  "label": "O",
  "id": "a95821fb-31d9-4773-b35b-a330f60145b3",
  "parentGroup": "5d7de0ab-7949-412c-acc3-8e6f2f63b6ca",
  "padding": 30
}];
```

I would like, based on the given data, to assign the depth of each group, starting from 1 for all the groups which have no parent (parentGroup == null).

My current approach is:

```
var mainGroups = groups.filter(function(group) {
  return group.parentGroup == null;
});

mainGroups.forEach(function(mainGroup) {
  var currentDepth = 1;
  mainGroup.depth = currentDepth;

  function assignDepths(group) {
    if (group.groups.length > 0) {
      currentDepth++;
      group.groups.forEach(function(subgroupIndex) {
        groups[subgroupIndex].depth = currentDepth;
      });
      group.groups.forEach(function(subgroupIndex) {
        assignDepths(groups[subgroupIndex]);
      });
    }
  }
  assignDepths(mainGroup);
});
```

However, that is not correct.
Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that each time you call `assignDepths`, you are incrementing `currentDepth`. In this line:                 `group.groups.forEach(function(subgroupIndex){ assignDepths(groups[subgroupIndex]); });`, you are calling `assignDepths` on *each* subgroup, which means that each time the loop moves to a new subgroup, you are incrementing `currentDepth` again. This means that if you have 2 subgroups that should be at the same depth, the second one that gets processed by that loop will get assigned a larger depth than the first (possibly several levels higher if the first subgroup has subgroups of its own.)

Working with the code you provided, a simple fix would be to use the current group's depth to calculate the depth of its subgroups. Try this instead:

```js
var groups = [
  {"leaves":[],"groups":[1],"label":"A","id":"5fe7a8ee-abd2-45d9-a79b-ff48e216f537","parentGroup":null,"padding":30}, 
  {"leaves":[],"groups":[2,5,8,9],"label":"B","id":"567e8de7-3aff-4b02-a891-b90a78bbf99f","parentGroup":"5fe7a8ee-abd2-45d9-a79b-ff48e216f537","padding":30}, 
  {"leaves":[],"groups":[3,4],"label":"C","id":"56d73322-2601-477c-8e6f-dc3623cc37ed","parentGroup":"567e8de7-3aff-4b02-a891-b90a78bbf99f","padding":30}, 
  {"leaves":[0],"groups":[],"label":"D","id":"cc4e72f8-1844-4334-9796-60a0e1566331","parentGroup":"56d73322-2601-477c-8e6f-dc3623cc37ed","padding":30}, 
  {"leaves":[1],"groups":[],"label":"E","id":"0ffbc1a8-8ce3-4e37-bf4f-6f3283a5d8d2","parentGroup":"56d73322-2601-477c-8e6f-dc3623cc37ed","padding":30}, 
  {"leaves":[],"groups":[6,7],"label":"F","id":"75b62737-0270-4569-8772-7d88eeffc801","parentGroup":"567e8de7-3aff-4b02-a891-b90a78bbf99f","padding":30},
  {"leaves":[2],"groups":[],"label":"G","id":"c69d6171-e834-4788-a206-64b7721a1022","parentGroup":"75b62737-0270-4569-8772-7d88eeffc801","padding":30}, 
  {"leaves":[3],"groups":[],"label":"H","id":"8f6b7a33-6156-4495-9ece-7acd16284ba8","parentGroup":"75b62737-0270-4569-8772-7d88eeffc801","padding":30},
  {"leaves":[4,5,6,7,8],"groups":[],"label":"I","id":"c4541ca8-c0f2-4694-a7a6-17092ad881ca","parentGroup":"567e8de7-3aff-4b02-a891-b90a78bbf99f","padding":30},
  {"leaves":[9],"groups":[],"label":"J","id":"f6f93345-991e-4759-8aaf-b65f016c4d8f","parentGroup":"567e8de7-3aff-4b02-a891-b90a78bbf99f","padding":30},
  {"leaves":[],"groups":[11,12,13,14],"label":"K","id":"5d7de0ab-7949-412c-acc3-8e6f2f63b6ca","parentGroup":null,"padding":30},
  {"leaves":[10,11],"groups":[],"label":"L","id":"a997ab55-d8f2-436b-95e2-1635d98fdb5d","parentGroup":"5d7de0ab-7949-412c-acc3-8e6f2f63b6ca","padding":30},
  {"leaves":[12],"groups":[],"label":"M","id":"3cbaed7e-e3ca-4686-beb6-2599e56981c6","parentGroup":"5d7de0ab-7949-412c-acc3-8e6f2f63b6ca","padding":30},
  {"leaves":[13],"groups":[],"label":"N","id":"033b3242-6ff9-4bf0-833f-2042b9cb6978","parentGroup":"5d7de0ab-7949-412c-acc3-8e6f2f63b6ca","padding":30},
  {"leaves":[14],"groups":[],"label":"O","id":"a95821fb-31d9-4773-b35b-a330f60145b3","parentGroup":"5d7de0ab-7949-412c-acc3-8e6f2f63b6ca","padding":30}
]

var mainGroups = groups.filter(function(group){return group.parentGroup == null;});

mainGroups.forEach(function(mainGroup){
    mainGroup.depth = 1;

    function assignDepths(group){
        if (group.groups.length>0){
            group.groups.forEach(function(subgroupIndex){ groups[subgroupIndex].depth = group.depth + 1; });
            group.groups.forEach(function(subgroupIndex){ assignDepths(groups[subgroupIndex]); });
        }
    }
    assignDepths(mainGroup);
});

console.log(groups)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const groups = [
  {"leaves":[],"groups":[1],"label":"A","id":"5fe7a8ee-abd2-45d9-a79b-ff48e216f537","parentGroup":null,"padding":30}, 
  {"leaves":[],"groups":[2,5,8,9],"label":"B","id":"567e8de7-3aff-4b02-a891-b90a78bbf99f","parentGroup":"5fe7a8ee-abd2-45d9-a79b-ff48e216f537","padding":30}, 
  {"leaves":[],"groups":[3,4],"label":"C","id":"56d73322-2601-477c-8e6f-dc3623cc37ed","parentGroup":"567e8de7-3aff-4b02-a891-b90a78bbf99f","padding":30}, 
  {"leaves":[0],"groups":[],"label":"D","id":"cc4e72f8-1844-4334-9796-60a0e1566331","parentGroup":"56d73322-2601-477c-8e6f-dc3623cc37ed","padding":30}, 
  {"leaves":[1],"groups":[],"label":"E","id":"0ffbc1a8-8ce3-4e37-bf4f-6f3283a5d8d2","parentGroup":"56d73322-2601-477c-8e6f-dc3623cc37ed","padding":30}, 
  {"leaves":[],"groups":[6,7],"label":"F","id":"75b62737-0270-4569-8772-7d88eeffc801","parentGroup":"567e8de7-3aff-4b02-a891-b90a78bbf99f","padding":30},
  {"leaves":[2],"groups":[],"label":"G","id":"c69d6171-e834-4788-a206-64b7721a1022","parentGroup":"75b62737-0270-4569-8772-7d88eeffc801","padding":30}, 
  {"leaves":[3],"groups":[],"label":"H","id":"8f6b7a33-6156-4495-9ece-7acd16284ba8","parentGroup":"75b62737-0270-4569-8772-7d88eeffc801","padding":30},
  {"leaves":[4,5,6,7,8],"groups":[],"label":"I","id":"c4541ca8-c0f2-4694-a7a6-17092ad881ca","parentGroup":"567e8de7-3aff-4b02-a891-b90a78bbf99f","padding":30},
  {"leaves":[9],"groups":[],"label":"J","id":"f6f93345-991e-4759-8aaf-b65f016c4d8f","parentGroup":"567e8de7-3aff-4b02-a891-b90a78bbf99f","padding":30},
  {"leaves":[],"groups":[11,12,13,14],"label":"K","id":"5d7de0ab-7949-412c-acc3-8e6f2f63b6ca","parentGroup":null,"padding":30},
  {"leaves":[10,11],"groups":[],"label":"L","id":"a997ab55-d8f2-436b-95e2-1635d98fdb5d","parentGroup":"5d7de0ab-7949-412c-acc3-8e6f2f63b6ca","padding":30},
  {"leaves":[12],"groups":[],"label":"M","id":"3cbaed7e-e3ca-4686-beb6-2599e56981c6","parentGroup":"5d7de0ab-7949-412c-acc3-8e6f2f63b6ca","padding":30},
  {"leaves":[13],"groups":[],"label":"N","id":"033b3242-6ff9-4bf0-833f-2042b9cb6978","parentGroup":"5d7de0ab-7949-412c-acc3-8e6f2f63b6ca","padding":30},
  {"leaves":[14],"groups":[],"label":"O","id":"a95821fb-31d9-4773-b35b-a330f60145b3","parentGroup":"5d7de0ab-7949-412c-acc3-8e6f2f63b6ca","padding":30}
]

const getDepth = (x, depth, arr) =>
  x.parentGroup === null
    ? depth
    : getDepth(arr.find(y => y.id === x.parentGroup), depth + 1, arr)

groups.forEach(x => x.depth = getDepth(x, 1, groups))

console.log(groups)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this should be the code you want

```js
function setDepth(a){
  return a.map(o => o.depth = o.groups.length ? Math.max(...o.groups.map(d => ++setDepth(o.groups.map(i => data[i]))[0])) : 0);
}
var data = [{"leaves":[],"groups":[1],"label":"A","id":"5fe7a8ee-abd2-45d9-a79b-ff48e216f537","parentGroup":null,"padding":30},{"leaves":[],"groups":[2,5,8,9],"label":"B","id":"567e8de7-3aff-4b02-a891-b90a78bbf99f","parentGroup":"5fe7a8ee-abd2-45d9-a79b-ff48e216f537","padding":30},{"leaves":[],"groups":[3,4],"label":"C","id":"56d73322-2601-477c-8e6f-dc3623cc37ed","parentGroup":"567e8de7-3aff-4b02-a891-b90a78bbf99f","padding":30},{"leaves":[0],"groups":[],"label":"D","id":"cc4e72f8-1844-4334-9796-60a0e1566331","parentGroup":"56d73322-2601-477c-8e6f-dc3623cc37ed","padding":30},{"leaves":[1],"groups":[],"label":"E","id":"0ffbc1a8-8ce3-4e37-bf4f-6f3283a5d8d2","parentGroup":"56d73322-2601-477c-8e6f-dc3623cc37ed","padding":30},{"leaves":[],"groups":[6,7],"label":"F","id":"75b62737-0270-4569-8772-7d88eeffc801","parentGroup":"567e8de7-3aff-4b02-a891-b90a78bbf99f","padding":30},{"leaves":[2],"groups":[],"label":"G","id":"c69d6171-e834-4788-a206-64b7721a1022","parentGroup":"75b62737-0270-4569-8772-7d88eeffc801","padding":30},{"leaves":[3],"groups":[],"label":"H","id":"8f6b7a33-6156-4495-9ece-7acd16284ba8","parentGroup":"75b62737-0270-4569-8772-7d88eeffc801","padding":30},{"leaves":[4,5,6,7,8],"groups":[],"label":"I","id":"c4541ca8-c0f2-4694-a7a6-17092ad881ca","parentGroup":"567e8de7-3aff-4b02-a891-b90a78bbf99f","padding":30},{"leaves":[9],"groups":[],"label":"J","id":"f6f93345-991e-4759-8aaf-b65f016c4d8f","parentGroup":"567e8de7-3aff-4b02-a891-b90a78bbf99f","padding":30},{"leaves":[],"groups":[11,12,13,14],"label":"K","id":"5d7de0ab-7949-412c-acc3-8e6f2f63b6ca","parentGroup":null,"padding":30},{"leaves":[10,11],"groups":[],"label":"L","id":"a997ab55-d8f2-436b-95e2-1635d98fdb5d","parentGroup":"5d7de0ab-7949-412c-acc3-8e6f2f63b6ca","padding":30},{"leaves":[12],"groups":[],"label":"M","id":"3cbaed7e-e3ca-4686-beb6-2599e56981c6","parentGroup":"5d7de0ab-7949-412c-acc3-8e6f2f63b6ca","padding":30},{"leaves":[13],"groups":[],"label":"N","id":"033b3242-6ff9-4bf0-833f-2042b9cb6978","parentGroup":"5d7de0ab-7949-412c-acc3-8e6f2f63b6ca","padding":30},{"leaves":[14],"groups":[],"label":"O","id":"a95821fb-31d9-4773-b35b-a330f60145b3","parentGroup":"5d7de0ab-7949-412c-acc3-8e6f2f63b6ca","padding":30}];
setDepth(data);
console.log(data);
```